# как найти что меняет линки

Tags: javascript, html

Есть через ухо написанный сайт, намешанно в нем дофига. В итоге при установке google analytics нифига не работает. Судя по всему javascript подменяет адрес google тк при просмотре кода страницы там все верно, но если смотреть через консоль дебагера в Chrome, то там ошибка GET запроса и URL уже идет с подставленным перед адресом google адреса самого сайта
типа:
http://moysait.ru/https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxx
Вопрос соответственно как найти ту заразу что это туда подставляет?

Comment: а есть ссылочка на сайт

Comment: поставить breakpoint на изменение аттрибутов ссылки

Comment: Попробуй сохранить страницу html локально, открой в браузере и поочередно удаляй подключенные скрипты js, и отслеживай когда ссылка останется нормальной.
Можно и не сохраняя страницу на комп, используя Local Overrides в chrome